# How do I add this function to my buttons?

Tags: c#

Can somebody tell me how to put the function ChooseImage() into every button click? I want it to assign a random picture every time I click one of the buttons

```
private void ChooseImage(Image imgOption)
{
    imgOption = picOption.Image;
    switch (intRandom)
    {
        case 0:
            imgOption = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\HP\source\repos\RockPaperScissors\RockPaperScissors\rock.png");
            break;
        case 1:
            imgOption = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\HP\source\repos\RockPaperScissors\RockPaperScissors\paper.jpg");
            break;
        case 2:
            imgOption = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\HP\source\repos\RockPaperScissors\RockPaperScissors\scissors.png");
            break;
    }
}

private void btnRock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void btnPaper_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void btnScissors_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: First try, what you think you could do??

Comment: Do you know how to call the function?

Comment: I know how to call a function it's just that when I try to call it in the buttons I get an error with the picturebox message

Comment: Are all the buttons setting the image for the same PictureBox?...or do they set their own (if yes, what are their names)?

Comment: Yes, they all share the same PictureBox, but I've fixed the problem. It was me referring to an Image in the method when I was trying to set a PictureBox for the .Forms application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Random class in C#

Here's the code.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
ChoseImage(image, rnd.Next(0, 3)) // Generates a number between 0 and 2
```

Also change your method to

```
private void ChooseImage(Image imgOption, int intRandom)
{
    imgOption = picOption.Image;
    switch (intRandom)
    {
        case 0:
            imgOption = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\HP\source\repos\RockPaperScissors\RockPaperScissors\rock.png");
            break;
        case 1:
            imgOption = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\HP\source\repos\RockPaperScissors\RockPaperScissors\paper.jpg");
            break;
        case 2:
            imgOption = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\HP\source\repos\RockPaperScissors\RockPaperScissors\scissors.png");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not answered the question. You just rewrote his function:-)

Comment: @preciousbetine Well I did that because it was working. He was just missing a parameter. Also I showed him how he can generate random numbers and pick a  random photo based on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of setting the image randomly for "picOption".  Note that I only loaded the images ONCE, at Form load, and stored them in a List for reference.  I also wired up all three buttons so they would fire the SAME handler when clicked (this can be done via the IDE instead of in code as I did):

```
Random R = new Random();
List<Image> images = new List<Image>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\HP\source\repos\RockPaperScissors\RockPaperScissors\rock.png"));
    images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\HP\source\repos\RockPaperScissors\RockPaperScissors\paper.jpg"));
    images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\HP\source\repos\RockPaperScissors\RockPaperScissors\scissors.png"));

    btnRock.Click += All_Buttons_Click;
    btnPaper.Click += All_Buttons_Click;
    btnScissors.Click += All_Buttons_Click;
}

private void All_Buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    picOption.Image = images[R.Next(images.Count)];
}
```

Let me know if you need to modify this so that each button outputs to a different PictureBox.  It's unclear to me what is happening in your program...